# Maven test SpringBootTest throws unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project with the following structure

```
src
|--- main
|    |--- java
|    |    |--- io.example.config
|    |    |    |--- AppConfig (Annotated @Cofiguration)
|    |    |--- io.example.beans 
|    |    |    |--- Bean1 (Annotated @Component)
|    |    |    |--- Bean2 (Annotated @Component)
|    |    |--- io.example.repository
|    |    |    |--- Repo (DynamoDB Crud Repo; Annotated @EnableScane)
|    |    |--- io.example.main
|    |    |    |--- Application (Annotated @SpringBootApplication)
|    |--- module-info.java
|--- test
|    |--- java
|    |    |--- io.example.main
|    |    |    |--- IntTest (Annotated @SpringBootTest)
```

The code in the *IntTest* class looks like

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class IntTest {
  ...
}
```

When I run the tests from IntelliJ it runs fine. But I run it from maven `mvn test` it throws the following error

```
Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
```

I read some of the documentation and similar questions in SO. **Most of the solution rectifies the package alignment between source and test folder.** Which is not a problem in my case.

**The test runs fine with `mvn test` when I do the following I explicitly define the context dependencies**

```
package io.example.main;

import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import io.example.config.AppConfig;
import io.example.beans.Bean1;
import io.example.beans.Bean2;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Application.class, AppConfig.class, Bean1.class, Bean2.class })
@SpringBootTest
public class IntTest {
  ...

  @Autowired
  private Bean1 b1;

  @Autowired
  private Bean2 b2;

  @Test
  public void testRandom() {
      /* assert statements */
  }
}
```

I can do the above, but is there any way I can run the tests without explicitly defining `ContextConfiguration`?

Comment: Please show the entire header of your `IntTest.java` in the last snippet (package, imports, everything).

Comment: That test file doesn't match the directory (package) structure you showed in your diagram.

Comment: I had to translate the symbols of the original code to different symbols for better readability and eliminating domain-specific details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put your `Application (Annotated @SpringBootApplication)` class in the package that is root of other packages. In your case it is `io.example` package.

Comment: This is the correct answer. My moving the main application class out of the root package you lose a lot of convention over configuration. The Spring Boot Application annotation will package scan from the root package and find the beans in the same or child packages. 

Additionally Slice tests and SpringBootTest will use this class to configure the test contexts.

Comment: I have done this. But still, I get the same error. I moved the `Application` class to `io.example`. I also moved `IntTest` accordingly so that it mimics src dir structure.

Comment: What happens if `IntTest` is in `io.example.main` package?

Answer (score 1):

@piradian has already provided a correct answer, I'll try to explain why is it correct.

`@SpringBootTest` annotation when placed on test in its most simplistic way (without parameters) tries to mimic the the process of starting the microservice for the test as precise as possible.

There are basically two steps it should do when it comes to the configuration retrieval:

- Find the spring boot application
- Find all configurations / components that should be loaded

For the first step, it first tries to find the `@SpringBootConfiguration` annotation. This is a meta-annotation  placed on `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. This is required to find all the registered components / configurations.

So it starts with the package where the test resides (`io.example.main`) and if it finds class with `@SpringBootConfiguration` in the same package (and yes, it founds it) - then it means that this is the base package to search for all configurations / components.
If it doesn't find a class like this, then it goes one package up (`io.example`) and start searching again, then if not found goes for (`io`)

When the class is found, it start to search for configuration / components **downwards** starting with the package where the application resides. This is exactly how spring boot application works. And this is the source of the failure:

`io.example.main` package doesn't have any "sub-packages" so the spring boot test finds nothing and that's why test fails.

If you move the SpringBootApplication one package up, this solves the issue. 
, because now the first step of the process described above searches in `io.example.main` package, finds nothing, searches in `io.example`, finds the required class and this is where it starts the second step from.

Now, if you use `@SpringBootTest` in conjunction with `@ContextConfiguration` this is like saying to spring boot: "Don't activate this two-phase search, just take the configuration classes that I supply and start from there". That's why it works for you with `@ContextConfiguration`